# Help with diagbox and line-wrap inside tables

Tags: tables, diagbox

I would love some help with this.

Basically, I am trying to have this table transposed, but either I am able to limit the size of each column (e.g. tabularx, tabu) to enable line-wrap or I have the \backslashbox working, not both. I also tried multirow, minipage without success.

Anyone got any idea?

Thanks in advance!

**edit1 as requested by Bernard:** Switching rows and columns is for presentation sake, since it does not look as good if it is vertical. Too many rows for these number of columns. The backslashbox or diagbox is to differentiate the variable from the value of the coefficient of the function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\title{aaa}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Coefficients and exponents for each variable}
\label{tab:tableofvalues}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
    \label{table:ratiocoefficientadimensionalised}
    \centering
    \backslashbox{Ratio}{Coefficient}   &   $\gamma$  &   $\tau$    &   $R^2$ \\ \hline
    aaaaaa                              &   1.000   &   0.50    &   1.00\\
    bbbbbbbbbbb                         &   1.000   &   0.50    &   1.00\\
    cccccccc                            &   1.000   &   0.50    &   1.00\\
    ddddddddd                           &   1.000   &   0.50    &   1.00\\
    eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee              &   1.000   &   0.50    &   1.00\\
    ffffff                              &   1.000   &   0.50    &   1.00\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \begin{table}[h]\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
        {\diagbox{Coefficient}{Ratio}} & {aaaaaa} & {bbbbbbbbbbb} &  {cccccccc} & {ddddddddd} &    {eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee} &   {ffffff} \\ \hline
        \\ \\ 
    \end{tabular}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, nor why you want to swap rows and columns or need a slashbox. Could you explain more?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use a slashbox, but would add a row above the other rows, with `coefficient` (or `ratio`) centred in a `\multicolumn{c}{#columns}{head}`, if you see what I mean